# How can I have my script run another script when a condition has been met? (Java)

Tags: java

I have a script that runs a Black Jack game in Java and currently it is set up in such way that if you lose (run out of money), a message will appear saying  that you lost and are out of money.

What I would like to do is to have it run a second script, when you run out of money. I've tried figuring it out but i can't seem to get it.

```
if (money == 0)
{
    System.out.println("Looks like you've are out of money!");
    break;
}
```

Comment: What kind of script do you want to run when this condition is true?

Comment: You will need to provide the additional script *after* the print statement and *before* the `break` command. As is, this question is vague at best and will be closed.

Comment: It's really not clear what you need.  If you included more code for context, perhaps we would have a better idea of what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a *method*. You can declare a method like this:

```
private static void myMethod () {

}
```

You can replace the word myMethod with the name of your second script. You can run (call) this method by

```
myMethod ();
```

And in the curly braces you can start writing your second script.

To Learn more about methods, read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html